# Caption styles for word_document2 in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I've got an `.Rmd` I need to output using the `word_document2` format with R bookdown. It has a `.docx` template which works fine for heading styles etc.

However, it appears that the figure/table captions are output using the "normal" style, so I can't control the font, size etc. on them as a group and am having to go through after the fact and change them all by hand. Is there a way to get bookdown to designate them to use Word's "caption" style, or alternatively to specify a custom style for them?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: Sorry - of course I should have done this in the first place. In making one I found the answer, which I've posted below. I can still include the example, but not sure if it's helpful anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In trying to make a reproducible example, I found the problem (apologies for not including an example in the first place).

The issue wasn't with the `.Rmd`, but the reference `.docx` itself. It had a "Caption" style, but for some reason it didn't have "Image Caption" or "Table Caption" styles, which is what markdown was looking for. I copied those styles over from another Word document according to [these instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-styles-and-autotext-between-documents-or-templates-87c7dde7-670c-43f4-a033-33309c86b61e), and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In your `YAML` header for your `.Rmd`, you can specify a Word doc to use as the basis for all formatting. Your rendered word doc will pick up all the styles from this `reference_docx` and apply them to your output:

```
---
title: "Example .Rmd"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    reference_docx: word-styles-reference-01.docx
theme: hpstr
fontsize: 11pt
---
```

The Word file that I am using for styles is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gSyE22hJbGdsTj6C-RWBTnyBVnG0XwB3

Comment: I had specified a `reference_docx`, yes - the issue was with the reference `.docx` itself, which I've posted in an answer.