# Figure name when knitting from R markdown (.Rmd) to Word document (.docx)

Tags: r, r-markdown, caption

I am preparing an `.Rmd` document that I will render into a `.docx`.  I want the figures to be labelled "Supplementary Figure 1: `<Caption>`", but I can't see how to override the default addition of "Figure 1: `<Caption>`" – which is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291833/figure-name-in-caption-using-rmarkdown) for PDF output.

A document template allows me to [change the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609212/caption-styles-for-word-document2-in-bookdown), but not the text content (as far as I can see).

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2: 
    reference_docx: "StyleTemplate.docx"
    fig_caption: true
---

```{r figWithCaption, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "(ref:caption)"}
variables <- 2
plot(cars) # figure content
` ``

(ref:caption) Caption to the figure might contain _markdown_ $^1$ or `r variables`
````

[Edit: Some of my figure captions contain markdown, which is supported by the "bookdown" package but (as far as I can see) not by "officedown"]

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve that would be to use the `officedown` package which enhances the possibilities of RMarkdown for Word considerably, including to set the prefix for figures via the YAML or via chunk options:

````
---
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    plots:
      caption:
        pre: "Supplementary Figure "
    fig_caption: true
---

```{r figWithCaption, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Caption"}
plot(cars)
```

```{r figWithCaption1, echo = FALSE, fig.cap = "Caption", fig.cap.pre = "Foo "}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

**EDIT** While `officedown` allows for rendering of markdown I haven't found an option to make your Rmd code work with `officedown`, i.e. works only if you set the caption in the chunk options.

A second but more advanced approach to achieve your desired result would be to use a LUA filter.

Adapting my answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505608/remove-colon-in-figure-caption-using-pandoc-and-bookdown-in-r-markdown/68508668#68508668) which is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505608/remove-colon-in-figure-caption-using-pandoc-and-bookdown-in-r-markdown/68508668#68508668) you could achieve your desired result by creating a LUA filter like so:

```
function Image (img)
  img.caption[1] = pandoc.Strong(pandoc.Str(string.gsub(img.caption[1].text, "Figure", "Supplementary Figure")))
  return img
end
```

Which could then be applied in your Rmd like so:

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2: 
    fig_caption: true
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter", "figure_caption_patch.lua"]
---

```{r figWithCaption, echo = FALSE, , fig.cap = "(ref:caption)"}
variables <- 2
plot(cars)
```

(ref:caption) Caption to the figure might contain _markdown_ $^1$
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question as asked – but can officedown handle figure captions that contain markdown? (I've revised the question with an example)

Comment: Hej Martin. While officedown can handle markdown I haven't found an option to set the caption outside of the chunk option. But see my edit for a second option.

Answer (score 0):

The links from @stefan's answer led me to [another solution](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-change-the-figure-table-caption-style-in-bookdown/110397):

Add a file `_bookdown.yml` to the same directory as `MyFile.Rmd`, with contents:

```yaml
language:
  label:
    fig: !expr function(x) sprintf("Supplementary Figure %s. ", x)
```

Full documentation of this feature is available [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html).